# How to change language of Oracle Client 12c Release 2

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, cjk, oracleclient, ora-01861

I have installed Oracle Client 12c Release 2 on my windows.
I want to change its language to Japanese, not English.
When I have some errors, I would like it shows error in Japanese.
I have set Region, language, datetime format before the install and installer shows in Japanese but then after finised, my code still shows messages in English. Installer have no choice for which language I would like to install product.
I have search google for this problem but I have no idea. Some people told me to change NLS value but I can't find it in regedit because it is oracle client not oracle database home (i think so).

Please help me, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
alter session set nls_language = 'JAPANESE';

select 1/0 from dual;

ORA-01476: 除数がゼロです
```

Answer (score 0):

The `NLS_LANG` environment variable determines the language of the user interface and the globalization behavior for components such as SQL*Plus, exp, and imp. It sets the language and territory used by the client application and the database user session. It also declares the character set for entering and displaying data by the client application.

The `NLS_LANG` environment variable uses the following format:

```
NLS_LANG=language_territory.characterset
```

In this format:

`language` specifies the language used for displaying user interface, error messages, sorting, day names, and month names

`territory` specifies the conventions for default date, monetary and numeric formats

`characterset` specifies the encoding of the database client, which is the character set for data entered or displayed by a client program

In most cases, this is the Oracle character set that corresponds to the Windows ANSI Code Page as determined by the System Locale.

The `NLS_LANG` parameter on Windows can be set

in Registry under the subkey corresponding to a given Oracle home,

as an environment variable.

When you install Oracle Database components and the NLS_LANG parameter is not yet set in the Registry subkey of the target Oracle home, Oracle Universal Installer sets the NLS_LANG parameter to a default value derived from the operating system locale for the current user.

**For example:**

Japanese - `JAPANESE_JAPAN.JA16SJISTILDE`

English (United Kingdom) - `ENGLISH_UNITED KINGDOM.WE8MSWIN1252`

English (United States) - `AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8MSWIN1252`

Please refer here for more information : [Installing and Using Oracle Components in Different Languages](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NTCLI/gblsupp.htm#NTCLI1349)